# Business process flow deployment issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

We are using Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise.
We created a managed solution to transfer our customizations to the production system. 
Part of those is a business process flow. 
Issue: We changed the BPF in the managed solution: We deleted steps and renamed steps. But those changes are not deployed to the production system.

The deploy log shows no errors. It shows our BPF as "imported". But the "workflow activation" is empty.

We tried deactivating the BPF in the target before importing it. No avail: The BPF in the target remains unchanged. Any ideas?